# Reasons why vscode extensions are not responding

Tags: visual-studio-code

It appears that my extensions are no longer working in VScode

For example, i have markdown PDF installed. If i click on an md file then hit F1 and select export PDF. I see (in the blue banner at the bottom of the window) a message "activating extension". It disappears and then nothing!

The same happens when i try to "open preview to the side" either by selecting F1 and preview or by clicking the icon at top right of window. The preview window doesn't open

I have uninstalled extensions and reinstalled, rebooted machine, tried several md's in different folders. No luck

I am a relatively new user to VScode so wondered if this is a common thing or if it is related to an update to VScode or something else. 
currently have VSCode 1.46.1

Thanks